# Pass parameters from URL to SOQL query.

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

How can i pass parameters from URL to Controller? I want to pass URL parameters to My controller class where i can query to fetch data with the help of these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch URL parameters by referring them in this way:

**Page name** = ExamplePage

=======

**URL example** =  `https://cs18.salesforce.com/apex/ExamplePage?yourParameter=90483753498hu76`

=======

In your controller, catch your parameter:

```
String yourParameterValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('yourParameter');
```

So, your String will have as value '90483753498hu76'

Now, you can query your data finding (e.g.) for your record using the parameter you just caught, i.e

```
Account exampleAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :yourParameterValue ];
```